# Can I use useState inside HOC (High order component)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, high-order-component

I have a HOC (High order component) that returns a functional component.
I want to use useState but I get this error message:

*“src/HOC.js
Line 5:35:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks”*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const HOC = (Component, data) => {
    return () => {
        const [count, setCount] = useState(data); // Error here
        const handleClick = () => {
            setCount(count + 1);
        };
        return (
            <Component
                countNumber={count}
                handleClick={handleClick}
            />
        )
    }
};

export default HOC;
```

```
import React from "react";
import HOC from "./HOC";

const LikesCount = ({countNumber, handleClick}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {countNumber} <br />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Like</button>
        </div>
    );
}

const EnhancedLikes = HOC(LikesCount, 5);

export default EnhancedLikes;
```

Is there any way to use useState in this HOC scenario?

Comment: Instead of having HOC, why not use custom hooks? as Hooks replaces HOC. I can post an answer if you want a custom hook that acts like an HOC (can be "hooked" on other components).

Comment: Syntex is not correct. you are closing block after setCount?

Comment: @RahulSharma that was a typo. Just fixed it.

Comment: @IamL it would be very interesting to see how that works if it lets me achieve the same.

Comment: @JohnBonjon I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I'll post the custom hook counterpart for the HOC above:

As far as I understand in your code, you want an HOC that you can just "hooked" to the component and it will perform a count.

so, you can create a custom hook:

```
const useCounter = (default = 0) => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(default);
      const [add, setAdd] = useState(0);
      const handleClick = (base = 0) => {
          setCount(count + base + add);
      };
      const onSetAdd = (e) => setAdd(e.target.value);
      
      return {count, handleClick, onSetAdd};
}
```

now to hook it in a functional component:

```
const LikesCount = () => {
    const {count, handleClick, onSetAdd} = useCounter(0);
    const onAddOne = () => handleClick(); // default is 1, so passing none = one
    const onAddTwo = () => handleClick(2);
    const onAddThree = () => handleClick(3);
   

    return (
        <div>
            <input type="number" onChange={onSetAdd} value={add} />
            {count} <br />
            <button onClick={onAddOne}>Like</button>
            <button onClick={onAddTwo}>Add 2</button>
            <button onClick={onAddThree}>Add 3</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LikesCount;
```

That's it, you can just then add the ff code on any components that you want to have a counter:

```
const {count, handleClick} = useCounter(0);
```

The code above acts exactly the same as the sample HOC that you provided.

Comment: It works but it may have a downside. What about if I want to pass a value (from an input) to the hook, so instead of always adding one, it will add the passed value?

Comment: @JohnBonjon That's easy, I've updated the answer for that specific scenario. All you have to do is add a parameter.

Comment: That´s not what I meant. I was saying if the user (from an input) can pass a value to add. (i.e 47). I can´t have 47 buttons. It needs to be an input. HOC let´s you do that.

Comment: @JohnBonjon that's easy, just add another function inside the hook and call it on your input. I edited my answer.